# Transfer Azure subscription transfer from one tenant to another tenant

Tags: azure, entra-id

I am working on a discovery phase for my client, who is looking to migrate subscriptions from one AD tenant to another.

Basically, I would like to know what all resource types are truly impacted and need potential re-work. Initially, I was conducting my analysis based on this article --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/transfer-subscription#understand-the-impact-of-transferring-a-subscription, but I feel like the list of impacted resources given here is bit short-sighted. For example, I was thinking that databricks or synapse may break OR may need a rebuild in the target tenant but is not mentioned in the above article.

Just a day ago, I stumbled upon this article --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources, where it gives us the supported and unsupported list of resource types that can be moved over b/w subscriptions within the same tenant , but I believe it may also be relevant across tenants. I feel like this article contains the right list than the first one, but do correct me if my understanding is wrong.

I used a resource graph and pulled the list of all client's current tenant resources - Look at the attached spreadsheet where I marked them as red for all impactful resource types on the first worksheet. Please review the list and let me know your opinion.

Also, if you done a subscription transfer before, please respond as I would like to know more about your experience, your migration approach, understand what else is required from the discovery standpoint, etc If you have any check-list/pre-requisite would be great help.

Thank you in advance for your help.